# Merge 2 Dataframes with Unequal Dates of Year, Month, Day, Hour

Tags: pandas, date, datetime, merge

I have been searching how to merge 2 dataframes with unequal dates. Each date column are integer data types in year, month, day, hour columns. Suppose the df1 looks like this:

```
    site    data1    year   month   day   hour
0   A       5.4      2018   01      01    0
1   A       5.1      2018   01      01    1
2   A       3.7      2021   01      01    0
3   A       6.4      2021   01      01    1
4   A       7.5      2021   01      01    2
5   A       3.9      2021   02      01    0
```

And df2 looks like this:

```
    site    data2    year   month   day   hour
0   A       3.9      2021   01      01    0
1   A       6.0      2021   01      01    1
2   A       7.9      2021   01      01    2
3   A       4.2      2021   02      01    0
4   A       6.8      2021   02      01    1
5   A       7.2      2021   02      01    2
6   A       4.4      2021   02      01    3
```

And, I need df3 to look like this after the merge:

```
    site    data1    data2  year   month   day   hour
0   A       3.7      3.9    2021   01      01    0
1   A       6.4      6.0    2021   01      01    1
2   A       7.5      7.9    2021   01      01    2
3   A       3.9      4.2    2021   02      01    0
```

Thank you. The attempts that I've tried don't achieve the desired result. I have tried this as my latest attempt and the hour data values repeat for some reason from df1. Here is what I've tried with an inner merge:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on=['site','year','month','day','hour'],how='inner')
```

Comment: what is the condition for merging? kindly add what you tried and where it failed, as that could be a useful guide when providing solutions

Comment: `df1.merge(df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most obvious would be df1.merge(df2), you can be more specific with:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on=['site','year','month','day','hour'],right_on=['site','year','month','day','hour'] ,how='inner')
```

and you get your desired result:

```
    site    data1   year    month   day hour    data2
0   A       3.7    2021     1       1   0       3.9
1   A       6.4    2021     1       1   1       6.0
2   A       7.5    2021     1       1   2       7.9
3   A       3.9    2021     2       1   0       4.2
```

to organize the columns you can use `df[['site','data1','data2','year','month','hour']]`